# nodejs/express and puppeteer detect with my puppeteer code is completed inside of the html file

Tags: node.js, express, puppeteer

I am using nodejs/puppeeteer and a route for a small api. I am simply trying to see when the puppeteer scripts are done. When its done, I want to show something in my HTML page. Not sure what i need to modify on the route. I just know I need to return the data when done and somehow check on the html page?

```js
const express = require('express')
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express()
const port = 1000


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static('public'));


const goToSite = async(url) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.waitFor(1000);
};

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})

app.post('/puppeteer', (req, res) => {

  goToSite(req.body.url);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the [response object](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res) `res` to send something once done:

```js
const goToSite = async (url, res) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.waitFor(1000);
  page.evaluate(() => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = 'done';
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  });

  const html = await page.content();
  res.send(html);
  res.end();
};

app.post('/puppeteer', (req, res) => {
  goToSite(req.body.url, res);
});
```

Comment: but can that show in the html page? like say i have a div i want to display?

Comment: oh, you mean you want to return the `page` (retrieved via puppet), and embed something in that?

Comment: yes, thats what i want--to display something hidden

Comment: oh yeah, nice idea! I've update my answer accordingly. The trick is to execute some javascript code on the page itself (interpreted by puppeteer) before exporting the content.

Comment: would this write it on the index.html page? Seems to just hang...and does nothing

Comment: It appends the div to whatever page is served on the url you provide.